# Is there a word for describing people who know many things but superficially?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an appropriate word for the antonym of "full-stack", as in programming? Someone who knows a lot of things just as a full-stack programmer, but without mastering them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"jack of all trades" can refer to someone who knows how to do many different things but is not really a master at any of them.

Comment: The full saying is exactly that: "A Jack of all trades, a master of none."

Answer (score 4):

***Dilettante***, defined by Dictionary.com

> a person who takes up an art, activity, or subject merely for
>   amusement, especially in a desultory or superficial way; dabbler"

Comment: **Dilettantish** makes a fine insult: http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/dilettantish

Answer (score 1):

In sports you might refer to a ***utility player***, in more general sense a ***factotum*** (from the Latin for "do it all").

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the word "**generalist**": "one whose skills, interests, or habits are varied or unspecialized", according to [Merriam-Webster.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generalist)

Answer (score -2):

**[Polymath](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymath)**

A person who posseses knowledge about diverse topics.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).